# Handle errors inside class, but raise in other script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, error-handling

I'm looking for a sound and practical approach to storing different errors and/or exceptions (i.e. `IOError`, `ValueError`, `<CustomError>`, etc.) inside a class instance, but refraining from `raise`-ing them straight away.
Instead I'd like to somehow communicate them to the script that `import`-ed and created the class instance in the first place, and `raise` the errors and exceptions there.

I'm not looking for a strategy on how to catch exceptions. For my custom exceptions, I use classes!

Is there a general approach for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a "container/collector" class which contains your custom exceptions (Of course, without raising). This collector call in my example is the `MyExceptions` class.

You can define an unique exception as a class which is inherited from the related built-in exception. You can find the build-in exceptions and the exception structure (bottom of page) on this page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

**The basic syntax of an unique exception:**

```
class MyException1(BaseException):
    """
    Exception is inherited from 'BaseException'.
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "This is my Exception1. Inherited from 'BaseException'"
```

You can set the message of the exception with the `__str__` or the `__repr__` magic methods (I have used the `__str__` in my example). It means, in the above example if you raise the `MyException1` exception then the message in the traceback will be `This is my Exception1. Inherited from 'BaseException'`. You can read more about these magic methods on the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/11502612

**my_exceptions.py:**

```
class MyExceptions(object):
    """
    Collector class of Unique Exceptions
    """

    class MyException1(BaseException):
        """
        Exception is inherited from 'BaseException'.
        """
        def __str__(self):
            return "This is my Exception1. Inherited from 'BaseException'"

    class MyException2(Exception):
        """
        Exception is inherited from 'Exception'.
        """
        def __str__(self):
            return "This is my Exception2. Inherited from 'Exception'"

    class MyValueError(ValueError):
        """
        Exception is inherited from 'ValueError'.
        """
        def __str__(self):
            return "This is my MyValueError. Inherited from 'ValueError'"

    class AttributeError(BaseException):
        """
        Redefined 'AttributeError'. Inherited from 'ValueError'
        """
        def __str__(self):
            return "Redefined 'AttributeError'. Inherited from 'ValueError'"
```

As you can see above my exception collector class is the `MyExceptions`. This class contains other classes and actually these are the unique exceptions. I have written more type of exceptions. The unique exceptions are inherited from different build-in exceptions and the last one shows how you can re-defined a built-in exception (more-or-less).

**Usage of these exceptions (test.py):**

```
import my_exceptions


def raise_my_exception1():
    raise my_exceptions.MyExceptions.MyException1


def raise_my_exception2():
    raise my_exceptions.MyExceptions.MyException2


def raise_my_value_error():
    raise my_exceptions.MyExceptions.MyValueError


def raise_my_attribute_error():
    raise my_exceptions.MyExceptions.AttributeError


def raise_original_attribute_error():
    raise AttributeError("This is the original (built-in) AttributeError exception")


function_list = [
    raise_my_exception1,
    raise_my_exception2,
    raise_my_value_error,
    raise_my_attribute_error,
    raise_original_attribute_error,
]

for func in function_list:
    try:
        func()
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)
```

As you can see in my above `test.py` file, I have imported the `my_exceptions.py` file as a Python module (import my_exceptions). The unique exceptions are raised in the functions. You can access the exceptions: `<Module.CollectorClass.Exception>`. The last `raise_original_attribute_error` function raises the built-in `AttributeError` with a custom message (It shows how you can separate your own `AttributeError` exception and the built-in `AttributeError`). The `function_list` list contains the references of the functions (With this solution I can call the function in a for loop and I don't need to call them one-by-one). In the for loop I defined a `try/except` structure and call the functions. I have used the `BaseException` built-in exception because it is the more wide exception in Python.

**Output of the script:**

```
>>> python2 test.py 
This is my Exception1. Inherited from 'BaseException'
This is my Exception2. Inherited from 'Exception'
This is my MyValueError. Inherited from 'ValueError'
Redefined 'AttributeError'. Inherited from 'ValueError'
This is the original (built-in) AttributeError exception
```

**You can catch your own exceptions in a try/except (Separately from others):**

```
import my_exceptions


def raise_my_exception1():
    raise my_exceptions.MyExceptions.MyValueError


def raise_other_exception():
    raise Exception("Unexpected exception")

for func in [raise_my_exception1, raise_other_exception]:
    try:
        func()
    except my_exceptions.MyExceptions.MyValueError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Handled exception. Do nothing!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Not handled exception. Raise it!")
        raise e
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python2 test.py 
This is my MyValueError. Inherited from 'ValueError'
Handled exception. Do nothing!
Unexpected exception
Not handled exception. Raise it!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise e
Exception: Unexpected exception
```

And of course, you have many choice to use this own exception collector.

**You can create an instance from the exception collector class:**

```
import my_exceptions

exception_collector = my_exceptions.MyExceptions()


def raise_my_exception1():
    raise exception_collector.MyValueError
```

If you are a strict `OOP` developer, your can inherited your "functional" class from your exception class. In that case your can use the exceptions as "instance exceptions" (with `self`). **Probably this way what you are looking for!**

**Example:**

```
import my_exceptions


class FunctionalClass(my_exceptions.MyExceptions):
    def raise_my_exception1(self):
        raise self.MyValueError

    def raise_other_exception(self):
        raise Exception("Unexpected exception")


functional_instance = FunctionalClass()

for func in [functional_instance.raise_my_exception1, functional_instance.raise_other_exception]:
    try:
        func()
    except my_exceptions.MyExceptions.MyValueError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Handled exception. Do nothing!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Not handled exception. Raise it!")
        raise e
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python2 test.py 
This is my MyValueError. Inherited from 'ValueError'
Handled exception. Do nothing!
Unexpected exception
Not handled exception. Raise it!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise e
Exception: Unexpected exception
```

Comment: `try: except ValueError` will catch `ValueError` only or both ValueError and child exception? I know you can catch `MyValueError`. But is it possible to make some flexible exception?

Comment: Sure, if you inherited your own exception (`MyValueError`) from the `ValueError` built-in exception and you use the `ValueError` in the `except` then both of `MyValueError` and `ValueError` will be caught. You can imagine the exceptions as a tree with parents and child and if you check a parent then all included child will be caught. This fact is true for the built-in exception, you can see the exception hierarchy here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy. You can make the most flexible own exception if you inherited it from the first parent (`BaseException`).

Comment: Furthermore, here is a very nice and deep page about Python exception facts: https://julien.danjou.info/python-exceptions-guide/